# Dedupe Rule - blank matches

Tags: duplicate-contacts

We have a custom field - 80% of our contacts have this custom field in their profile - the rest are blank.

We setup a rule - if 7 characters or more of the custom filed are a match - it meets the threshold - however - contacts with blank custom fields are coming up as possible duplicates. Why is that?

Latest Civi - Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's coming from [line 179](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.16/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/Rule.php#L179) in CRM/Dedupe/BAO/Rule.php, but it looks as if it's been like this forever so I'm not sure if there's a reason.

If you change [line 76](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.16/CRM/Dedupe/BAO/Rule.php#L76) where it sets `$on` to be the below code instead, it makes it work but I can't immediately see if that has any side-effects for other types of rules.

```
    $on = [
      "SUBSTR(t1.{$this->rule_field}, 1, {$this->rule_length}) = SUBSTR(t2.{$this->rule_field}, 1, {$this->rule_length})",
      "t1.{$this->rule_field} IS NOT NULL",
      "t1.{$this->rule_field} <> ''",
    ];
```

Note that dedupe checking caches results, so **after you make that change clear cache** at admin - system settings - cleanup caches.

Comment: Thank you for this - I wonder if there is a solution that does not involve changing core.

Comment: It might be possible to add these criteria via an extension with https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_dupeQuery.